# PIC and LCD Conflict on PORTC

Tags: lcd

I am working on a PIC project to connect it to a LCD in 4 bit mode.  My data lines for my LCD are connected to my PORTC (PORTC0-3), but I need 4 pins from PORTC to connect to a 4 switches also (PORTC4-7).  The PIC is a PIC16F886.  The code for my LCD.c is below.

```
/*
 *  LCD Interface Example
 *  This code will interface to a standard LCD controller
 *  like the Hitachi HD44780.  It uses it in 4 bit mode, with 
 *  the hardware connected as follows (the standard 14 pin
 *  LCD connector is used):
 *
 *  PORTC bits 0-3 are connected to LCD Data Bits 4-7 (High Nibble)
 *  PORTA bit 2 is connected to the LCD RS input (Register Select)
 *  RW input (Read/Write) is connected to Ground
 *  PORTA bit 1 is connected to the LCD EN bit (Enable)
*/

#include    <htc.h>
#include    "lcd.h"

void pause (unsigned short usvalue);            //Establish pause routine function

#define LCD_RS          RA2
#define LCD_RW          RA4
#define LCD_EN          RA1
#define LCD_DATA        PORTC
#define LCD_STROBE()    ((LCD_EN = 1), (LCD_EN = 0))
#define  DelayS(T)              {unsigned char i; for (i = 0; i < T * 10; i++) __delay_ms(100);}    //Delay Macro
#define  _XTAL_FREQ             4000000

/*Write a byte to the LCD in 4 bit mode*/

void
lcd_write(unsigned char c)
{
    __delay_ms(1);
    LCD_DATA = ((c >> 4) & 0x0F);
    LCD_STROBE();
    LCD_DATA = (c & 0x0F);
    LCD_STROBE();
}

/*Clear and Home the LCD*/

void
lcd_clear(void)
{
    LCD_RS = 0;
    lcd_write(0x1);
    __delay_ms(2);
}

/*Write a string of characters to the LCD*/

void
lcd_puts(const char * s)
{
    LCD_RS = 1;                                 //Write Characters
    while(*s)
    {
        lcd_write(*s++);
    }
}

/*Write one character to the LCD*/

void
lcd_putch(char c)
{
    LCD_RS = 1;                                 //Write Characters
    lcd_write(c);
}

/*Go to the Specified Position*/

void
lcd_goto(unsigned char pos)
{
    LCD_RS = 0;
    lcd_write(0x80 + pos);
}

/*Initialize the LCD - put into 4 bit mode*/

void
lcd_init()
{
    char init_value;

    ANSEL = 0;                                  //Disable Analog Pins on PORTA

    init_value = 0x3;
    TRISA = 0;
    TRISC = 0;
    LCD_RS = 0;
    LCD_EN = 0;
    LCD_RW = 0;

    __delay_ms(15);                                 //Wait 15ms after Power applies)
    LCD_DATA = init_value;
    LCD_STROBE();
    __delay_ms(10);
    LCD_STROBE();
    __delay_ms(10);
    LCD_STROBE();
    __delay_ms(10);
    LCD_DATA = 2;                               //Four Bit Mode
    LCD_STROBE();

    lcd_write(0x28);                            //Set Interface Length
    lcd_write(0xF);                             //Display On, Cursor On, Cursor Blink
    lcd_clear();                                //Clear Screen
    lcd_write(0x6);                             //Set Entry Mode
}
```

Is there any way to "break" up PORTC so I can use it for both the LCD and the switches.

Thanks for any help provided.

Answer (score 3):

Here can make the upper 4 bits as input and the lower 4 bits output, simply by configuring the TRISSC register.

The code is

```
                      TRISC = 0xF0;
```

now you just send your data to the port, and only the output pins will be get changed.

You can use,

```
                       PORTC = data;
```

Now only the Lower nibble will be send to the LCD.

Writing

```
                        PORTC = data>>4;
```

Will send only the Upper nibble to the LCD.

Now to read the switches,

use

```
                        data = PORTC>>4;
```

now you will get the upper nibble of the PORTC to the lower nibble of `data`

otherwise you can use like this,

```
if(RC4) doThis(1);
else if(RC4) doThis(2);
else if(RC4) doThis(3);
else if(RC4) doThis(4);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
TRISC = 0xF0;
```

Or, more verbosely:

```
TRISCbits.TRISC0 = 0;
TRISCbits.TRISC1 = 0;
TRISCbits.TRISC2 = 0;
TRISCbits.TRISC3 = 0;
TRISCbits.TRISC4 = 1;
TRISCbits.TRISC5 = 1;
TRISCbits.TRISC6 = 1;
TRISCbits.TRISC7 = 1;
```

Then you can write with

```
PORTC = MyData;
```

Or

```
PORTCbits.RC3 = 1;
```

And read with

```
MyVar = PORTC;
```

or

```
if(PORTCbits.RC6==1)
{
    ....
}
```

etc.